# How to fix flickering issue in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am quite new to Jquery Mobile Framework.

I am using page transition in jqm .. Using this i am getting flickering issues while loading the content.

I used:

```
changepage("#id",{transition : "slide"})
```

There is no issue in the transition effect, but the flickering makes my site bad.

I used version : 1.2.0 jquery mobile js and css and jquery 1.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are getting a flickering? On Android or on every device?

Anyway, you can try to use their recommendation:

```
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Another check that you can try is [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5431).

Comment: Thanks , But this didnt worked out for me. Even i tried the solution from your given,No luck . My css and js are compressed version. I am facing this issue in Android and Iphone 5

Comment: Are you using fixed header and footer?

Comment: Yes, I am using fixed header

Comment: Try to check it without fixed header. If it will work without flickering, there is not a lot to do. It's a bad implementation of position: fixed on mobile devices. Read this article http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/12/the_fifth_posit.html

Comment: Thanks Dima , Fix header removal worked in most of the devices. But in IPhone 5 it is not working.Is there any solution for IPhone 5 ?

Comment: Try to add .ui-page from the answer, if it won't help, try to update your jQuery mobile version. Hope it will help.

Comment: Compressed version of jQuery mobile it's just fine. Add custom CSS file after jQuery Mobile CSS and put .ui-page there. It will override their rules.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. What I did was disable the transition.

If you are still having flickering without the transition then it might hint that the JavaScript is taking too long to run. You can fix this by simplifying the CSS and JavaScript until the flickering stops or by checking the performance of the page by using Chrome DevTools like [this blog post](http://addyosmani.com/blog/gone-in-sixty-frames-per-second/) suggests.